# Load file form root of rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to rails. I uploaded image to root of rails project folder. I want to access this image in show method. I write some code by googling, they are not working. Can anybody help on this?

My code is

```
<%=  "#{Rails.root}/uploads/works/#{upload.id}#{upload.fileextension}" %>
```

It returns

```
http://localhost:3000/home/user/Documents/rails/TimeTracker/uploads/works/6.jpg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails is very strong on sticking to conventions.

one big convention in rails is that images should be uploaded into the app/assets/images directory. you shouldn't be putting it in the root directory.

Then you can use the `image_tag` helper.

Sticking to Rails conventions (where possible) will make your life *much* easier and make your code easy to understand and maintain

have a read through the [documentation on rails assets](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) to get a better understanding on how rails expects you to deal with images (and other assets)

Answer (score 0):

You could use like this. Hope it works.

```
<%= image_tag "#{upload.id}#{upload.fileextension}", :alt => "image name" %>
```

Comment: Its not working, becoz my upload folder in root of the project